# Error when i try to create a ralationship: Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed - MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to create a relationship in a table, but i get this error: "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed", when i try to create a relationship.

Tables:
repository_files:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `repository_files` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `repository_files_id_user_foreign` (`id_user`),
  CONSTRAINT `repository_files_id_user_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`) REFERENCES `repository_m_users` (`CODUSU`)
)
```

repository_file_var_values:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `repository_file_var_values` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `file_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `var` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `value` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

The error is when i try the follow:

```
alter table `repo_file_var_values` 
add constraint `repo_file_var_values_file_id_foreign` 
foreign key (`file_id`) 
references `repo_files` (`id`)
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues:

1. FK to repository_m_users in your first table. I cannot see the code, but you may have an issue there.
2. Your table names are wrong. Change

```
alter table `repo_file_var_values` 
add constraint `repo_file_var_values_file_id_foreign` 
foreign key (`file_id`) 
references `repo_files` (`id`)
```

to

```
alter table `repository_file_var_values` 
add constraint `repo_file_var_values_file_id_foreign` 
foreign key (`file_id`) 
references `repository_file_var_values` (`id`)
```

3. Finally, change file_id type to match PK:

```
`file_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
```

to

```
`file_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
```